# Delete values from pandas dataframe based on logical operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete the values that are greater than a certain threshold from a pandas dataframe. Is there an efficient way to perform this? I am doing it with apply and lambda, which works fine but a bit slow for a large dataframe and I feel like there must be a better method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [1,2,3,4,5]})
df

    A   B
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   4   4
4   5   5
```

How can this be done without apply and lambda?

```
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A'] if x['A'] < 3 else None, axis=1)
df


    A    B
0   1.0  1
1   2.0  2
2   NaN  3
3   NaN  4
4   NaN  5
```

Comment: You've substantially changed your question now, are you wanting to just overwrite the A column now?

Comment: Sorry I had to update my question to clarify my point. Yes I want to delete some values in one column where they are above certain threshold.

Comment: See the last part of my updated answer

Comment: This is great. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [boolean mask](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) against the df:

```
In[21]:
df[df<3]

Out[21]: 
     A
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  NaN
```

Here where the boolean condition is not met a `False` is returned, this will just mask out the df value returning `NaN`

If you actually want to drop these rows then self-assign:

```
df = df[df<3]
```

To compare a specific column:

```
In[22]:
df[df['A']<3]

Out[22]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
```

If you want `NaN` in the removed rows then you can use a trick where a double square brackets will return a single column df so we can mask the df:

```
In[25]:
df[df[['A']]<3]

Out[25]: 
     A
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  NaN
```

If you have multiple columns then the above won't work as the boolean mask has to match the orig df, in which case you can `reindex` against the orig df index:

```
In[31]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [1,2,3,4,5]})
df[df['A']<3].reindex(df.index)

Out[31]: 
     A    B
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
```

**EDIT**

You've updated your question again, if you want to just overwrite the single column:

```
In[32]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [1,2,3,4,5]})
df['A'] = df.loc[df['A'] < 3,'A']
df

Out[32]: 
     A  B
0  1.0  1
1  2.0  2
2  NaN  3
3  NaN  4
4  NaN  5
```

Comment: How can I apply this to only certain column? As you know `df[df.A < 3]` only returns row 0 and 1.